# How will I get my money back?

Tags: xbox-one

I'm not quite sure how to explain this but, I'll try my best. So, I bought a $50 Xbox gift card for myself. I entered the code on the back of the card on my Xbox so I could have money to buy something. I ended up buying a 20$ game but, I realized that I didn't like it. If I were to get a refund, would I get my money back? I'm asking this because, I also have a PayPal connected to my Xbox account. I'm just wondering if the money will go to my PayPal or my Xbox currency.

Answer (score 8):

If you request the refund within 14 days of purchase of the game, Microsoft will credit your xbox account, not the paypal. Be sure to have your order number (it would be in your email) on hand.

You can start the refund process on their main store page, here https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/subscriptions-billing/buy-games-apps/refund-orders